# Who create trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016, someone create a trigger in a table within my database which is harmful for data row. This trigger looks like this.

```
create trigger [dbo].[mdl_oauth2_issuer_trigger] on [dbo].[mdl_oauth2_issuer] after update as set nocount on;  begin update mdl_oauth2_issuer set clientid = REPLACE(clientid, 'l', '1'); end
```

Please note that this trigger replace everything from "L" to "1"

I want to know who create this trigger (IP Address, SQL Server username)
Please help, thank you.

Comment: I imagine you're more likely to get an answer from [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), as this is more of a database operations/auditing question than a programming one.

Comment: You can get created date and time of trigger by query on sys.triggers however this is related to DB admin area you can contact them.

Comment: Stop using a shared SQL user account, and stop allowing just anyone to create things by using accounts properly, and you won't have this sort of issue. If you make everyone a DB administrator, and they're all using the same account, then you can't tell who did something. Learn to use roles and rights in your database properly. If you want everyone under the same account, restrict that account to only those things you want them to be able to do. If you allow everyone to do something harmful, it's too late after they've done so to worry about who did it..

Answer (score 1):

if your database has unique user auth you can determine that with this query :

```
SELECT
    objects.*,
    schemas.name as schema_name,
    ISNULL(po.name, ps.name) AS object_owner,
    ISNULL(po.type_desc, ps.type_desc) as owner_type
FROM sys.all_objects AS objects
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS schemas on objects.schema_id = schemas.schema_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals po ON objects.principal_id = 
po.principal_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals ps ON schemas.principal_id = 
ps.principal_ID
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I know IP address, because we use shared sql user.